# Netbeans/Aptana/RubyMine debugger in Windows 7 (64bit) + Ruby 1.8.7 + Rails 2.3.x does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, debugging

When I start the debugger I get the following error:

```
Netbeans "couldn't connect to server"
```

When I look at the editor log I see the following exception:

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- require_relative (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/linecache-0.45/lib/linecache.rb:66
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:32:in `gem_original_require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:32:in `require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.4/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:3
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta5/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:5
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta5/bin/rdebug-ide:7
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1
```

I am on:

```
Windows 7 (64bit)
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.9
```

I am using following debug related gems:

```
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.9)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.4 mswin32)
linecache (0.45)
```

**Note**: I was able to reproduce the same issue on RubyMine and Aptana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [issue](https://gist.github.com/1022875) is due to the latest version of `linecache` gem and I had to revert to an older version(`0.43`).

I did the following to fix the issue:

```
gem uninstall ruby-debug-ide ruby-debug-base linecache
gem install ruby-debug-ide
```

Re-install `ruby-debug-base` gem

```
gem uninstall ruby-debug-base
gem install  ruby-debug-base --platform mswin32
```

Re-install `linecache` gem

```
gem uninstall linecache
gem install  linecache  -v 0.43
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! gem uninstall linecache gem install linecache -v 0.43 The above lines sovled the same output error that I was having when I tried to run ruby-debug. I was originally using linecache v 0.45 also, which seemed to be the culprit.

Comment: Thank you, I was having the exact error as you with Aptana. Install 0.43 of linecache fixed it.

Comment: Had to run this instead of the 2nd line `gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby --pre`

Comment: I get this error after following all this:  Could not find ruby-debug-base

Answer (score 0):

to get the debugger running with ruby 1.8.7

```
gem install rake -v 10.4.2
```

download and unzip DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads to a location of your choice

cd to the installation location and run
    ruby dk.rb init
    ruby dk.rb install

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide -v 0.6.0
```

(tested with aptana IDE)